# Как прописать дефолтный язык React-приложению?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как явно объявить язык сайту, генерируемому Реакт-приложением?

Что-то вроде того, что в HTML достигается `<html lang="ru">`.

Comment: У вас есть html-файл в папке public, прописывайте там

Comment: `<html lang="ru">` - а собственно чем вас этот вариант не устраивает?

Comment: @Listopad02 В имеющемся проекте, в /public лежат исключительно шрифты и *.svg. Я нашел место откуда генерится <head> со всем его содержимым. Но это, к сожалению, мне не помогло. :)

Comment: @T0xee.n17 Устраивает на все 100%. Я не понимаю, как заставить Реакт генерировать эту конструкцию.

Comment: Используйте HTMLWebpackPlugin

Comment: @T0xee.n17 Спасибо! Сейчас буду разбираться.